# can't cast wrapper to object

Tags: java, casting, wrapper

I have two long variables and I wanted to cast them to an object type. I know that if I cast the long variables to Long wrapper, then cast the wrappers to an object it will work, but the compiler says "cannot cast from Long to text" text is an a object type.

```
private quantity start;
private quantity end;

public quantity(long s , long e) {
    Long e1 = (Long) e;
    Long s1 = (Long) s;
    start = (quantity) s1;
    end = (quantity) e1;
}
```

Comment: But a `Long` isn't a `text`, so what makes you think you can cast it to one?

Comment: text is just an example, I don't want to convert long to string. I want to convert it to another object which is a number.

Comment: Instead of trying to make up hypothetical examples, you should instead post actual code to avoid this sort of issue. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship between `text` and `Long` for that reason any attempts to cast from `text` to `Long` or vice versa will result in failure.

A cast is only possible where there is a relationship between the two given types.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get text, a string, to a long, or other numeric data type, you would have to convert it with the data types parse method.

What Aomine mentioned about relationship is correct.
Short -> Integer -> Long

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to have a string representation of long then you can use the following.

```
Long.toString(number);
```

and then you can assign it to the text type. I am assuming here that text is representing some string data.

Comment: No, text is just an example of my actual code, text is a number, I picked the name randomly.